# Java - @ResponseBody String - error 200

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm trying to get a `string response` from my controller but I get the below error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…) "Error 200"

When I change the response to a boolean or a different type, it's working ok. The problem is when I try to return a string.

js code:

```
 $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: "./signup",
   data: _data,
   dataType: "json",
   contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8",
   success : function(data) {
       console.log(data)
   },
   error : function(qXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
       console.log(errorThrown, "Error " + qXHR.status);
   }
  });
```

controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"text/plain", "application/*"})
    public @ResponseBody String signup(@RequestBody UserSignup details) {
       //...
        return message;
    }
```

any idea how can I solve this problem? I have tried a few things but nothing work. I think the response format is wrong as what the code expects.

**Edit**

I have changed my code(removed `produces`) but I still getting the same error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input(…) "Error 200"

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String signup(@RequestBody UserSignup details) {
        message = "ok";
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I don't have problem when the response is different stuff as a `String` I have solved the problem creating my own object. So below is the code:

```
public class Response<T> {
    private T message;
    private Exception ex;

    public Exception getEx() {
        return ex;
    }

    public void setEx(Exception ex) {
        this.ex = ex;
    }

    public T getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(T message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}


@Controller
public class MyControllerController {
    private Response<String> _response;
    private String message;

    public MyController() { _response = new Response<>(); }

 @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody Response<String> signup(@RequestBody UserSignup details) {
        try{
            message = "";
             // code...
            _response.setMessage(message);
            return _response;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            _response.setEx(ex);
            return _response;
        }
    }
}
```

response example in the browser:

> Object {message: "", ex: null}

Answer (score 5):

Your method is wrong. You are saying to produce **produces = {"text/plain", "application/*"}** But you are also adding the @ResponseBody which will generate JSON format response.

I would suggest you remove the attribute produces. And verify the string you are returning is well formed

Comment: I have tried removing the ``produces`` and I'm trying to return an string like "ok" and I still getting the same error. @cralfaro

Comment: @gon250 could you please update your question with the data you are testing right now? and the error message? just to be updated at same point as you

Comment: I have added the new code. basically I have removed the produces and I make sure I return a string.

Comment: remove contentType : "application/json;charset=UTF-8", from your ajax call, and the url is right?? you have a dot url: "./signup",

Comment: I have tried all the changes you told me and nothing work(I was getting the same error). I did a different stuff to get it working as I added in an answer. @cralfaro http://stackoverflow.com/a/40607383/2545964

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap your response in ResponseEntity class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> signup(@RequestBody UserSignup details) {
        message = "ok";
        return new ResponseEntity<>(message, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Also double check data that you are sending to server, maybe this is the problem, can you show us _data value?